# DLL Import use SYSTEMTIME

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dllimport

I have a dll developed using C++. Now I wish to use these functions in my C# application.
I know how to use the dll in my application, but my problem is that the dll expects a parameter which is of type SYSTEMTIME.

```
[DllImport("MyControl.dll")]
 public static extern Int32 MyCONTROL_NewControl(SYSTEMTIME stime);
```

But I am not able to use the `SYSTEMTIME` in my C# code. Please suggest a workaround on how to use `SYSTEMTIME`.

Comment: You have to tell as more specifically why you are not able to use it? Is it just that you don't have a C# definition for it? A possible definition for `SYSTEMTIME` to be used in P/Invoke scenarios can be found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SYSTEMTIME.html).

Comment: Because when I compile it says namespace or definition not found.

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SYSTEMTIME.html

Comment: @xaria you need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: @rekire http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SYSTEMTIME {
    Int16 wYear;
    Int16 wMonth;
    Int16 wDayOfWeek;
    Int16 wDay;
    Int16 wHour;
    Int16 wMinute;
    Int16 wSecond;
    Int16 wMilliseconds;
}
```

See also the ready to use solution from [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SYSTEMTIME.html) like [Christian.K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21567/christian-k) pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

That's how you use it in c#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SYSTEMTIME
    {
        ushort wYear;//ushort = WORD
        ushort wMonth;
        ushort wDayOfWeek;
        ushort wDay;
        ushort wHour;
        ushort wMinute;
        ushort wSecond;
        ushort wMilliseconds;
    }
```